# RouteLink as linkname

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there someway to render RouteLink as the name of the link aswell?

i.e

```
<%= Html.RouteLink(...., "myRoute", new { id = 75 }) %>
```

gets rendered as

```
<a href="http://foo/Something/75">http://foo/Something/75</a>
```

Is there some neat trick för that?

/M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an extension method to handle it for you

```
public static string PrintRouteLink (this HtmlHelper helper, string routeName, int id)
{
    UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
    return helper.RouteLink(url.RouteUrl(routeName,new { id =  id}),routeName,new { id =  id});
}
```

Then you can use:

```
<%= Html.PrintRouteLink(routeName,75) %>
```